# How to merge nested observables in a pipe rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular app I retrieve a list of post from an API call and, for each fo the posts, I have to do another API call to retrieve the number of likes.
I can't think of a clean way to do it, but current attempt of a solution is the following:

```
apiCall.pipe(
  switchMap((posts: Post[]) => {
    return posts.map((post: Post) => {
      return this.getPostLikes(post.rootMessage).pipe(
        map((likes: Like[]) => {
          post.rootMessage.reactions = likes;
          return post;
        }),
      );
    });
  }),
  mergeAll(),
  map((res: Post[]) => {
    return { res, currentPage: page + 1 };
  }),
)
```

I feel like the entire approach is wrong, but I can't think at any other strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tangent note: making everything an inline anonymous function makes code hard to read. How about more verbose, but easier to maintain style:

```
private getLikesForPostsArray = (posts: Post[]) => forkJoin({
  posts: of(posts),
  likes: forkJoin(posts.map((post: Post) => this.getPostLikes(post.rootMessage))),
});

private updateReactionsForPosts = ({posts, likes}: { posts: Post[], likes: Like[] }) =>
  posts.map((post: Post, index: number) => ({
    rootMessage: {...post.rootMessage, reactions: likes[index]},
    ...post,
  }));

//...

return apiCall.pipe(
  switchMap(this.getLikesForPostsArray),
  map(this.updateReactionsForPosts),
  map((res: Post[]) => ({
    res,
    currentPage: page + 1 // I don't see where `page` is defined
  })),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on whether you want to make the requests in parallel or one after another. Your solution right now with `mergeAll()` will make all requests at the same time but I think you can make it more simple without `mergeAll()`:

```
apiCall.pipe(
  switchMap((posts: Post[]) =>
    merge(posts.map(post => this.getPostLikes(post.rootMessage).pipe(
      map(likes => ({ likes, rootMessage: post.rootMessage})), // Just to be able to pair post with a response
    ))).pipe(,
      scan((acc, {likes, rootMessage}) => {
        const post = acc.find(p => p.rootMessage === response.rootMessage);
        post.rootMessage.reactions = likes;
        return acc;
      }, posts),
      last(), // Emit only once when all request have completed
    )
  }),
```